# Convertir lista anidada a dataframe

Tags: python, lista, pandas, dataframe, clase-anidada

Hola necesito convertir a DF la siguiente estructura:

```
fail = [{'Plano': 'iubcp', 'dato': {'VLAN': ['VL308_iub_1', 'VL309_iub_2'], 'address': ['10.210.242.69/29', '10.210.242.77/29'], 'owner': ['/QNIUB-2', '/QNIUB-3']}}]
```

intente con:

```
df= pd.json_normalize(fail, max_level=1)
```

resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que busco es conseguir esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

edito:

Estoy probando y veo que restructurando el formato de la lista "fail", dejándolo como diccionario y aplicando df = pd.DataFrame () obtengo lo que busco, pero no logro ver/entender como realizarlo, o sea,

```
fail= [{'Plano': 'iubcp', 'dato': {'VLAN': ['VL308_iub_1', 'VL309_iub_2'], 
'address': ['10.210.242.69/29', '10.210.242.77/29'], 'owner': ['/QNIUB-2', 
'/QNIUB-3']}}]
```

aplico-> `a = [{**x, **x.pop('dato')} for x in fail]` # para quitar la key "dato"

obtengo la lista -> `[{'Plano': 'iubcp', 'VLAN': ['VL308_iub_1', 'VL309_iub_2'],  'address': ['10.210.242.69/29', '10.210.242.77/29'], 'owner':  ['/QNIUB-2', '/QNIUB-3']}]`

y ahora necesitaría extráelo de la lista para que sea un diccionario pero no se como hacerlo:

```
fail_dic ={'Plano': 'iubcp', 'VLAN': ['VL308_iub_1', 'VL309_iub_2'], 
'address': ['10.210.242.69/29', '10.210.242.77/29'], 'owner': ['/QNIUB-2', 
'/QNIUB-3']}
```

y aquí: `df = pd.DataFrame(fail_dic)`

espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Respecto a tu edición, ¿no sería simplemente `fail_dic = fail[0]`? Al menos así es en este caso en que la lista `fail` contiene un solo diccionario. Si fuera más de uno necesitarías juntarlos todos en uno solo, concatenando las diferentes sub-listas,  pero la cosa se complicaría porque entonces se "desincronizaría" la lista con los nombres de planos, por ser más corta que las otras. Creo que la solución que te doy en la respuesta es más genérica.

Comment: Tenes razón @abulafia es así no lo estaba viendo! mala mía!  la solución genérica es la mas acertada para este caso.. muchas gracias impecable como siempre... saludos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez has llegado a tener la tabla que te da `json_normalize()`, es decir, esta:

```
   Plano                   dato.VLAN                          dato.address            dato.owner
0  iubcp  [VL308_iub_1, VL309_iub_2]  [10.210.242.69/29, 10.210.242.77/29]  [/QNIUB-2, /QNIUB-3]
```

Debes aplicar `.explode()` sobre cada columna, para que convierta esas listas en varias filas. Puedes hacer que se haga sobre todas las columnas mediante `apply()`, así:

```
df = df.apply(lambda c: c.explode())
```

El resultado será:

```
   Plano    dato.VLAN      dato.address dato.owner
0  iubcp  VL308_iub_1  10.210.242.69/29   /QNIUB-2
0  iubcp  VL309_iub_2  10.210.242.77/29   /QNIUB-3
```

Comment: excelente @abulafia muy interesante el método es lo que necesito! como comentario acabo de editar mi post con otra consulta al respecto... desde ya muchas gracias por tu tiempo... saludos